# Spring MVC @Autowired and @ModelAttribute HTTP Status 404 - /WEB-INF/circle.jsp

Tags: java, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, autowired, modelattribute

*Good day to you all, friends! Whatever I try, I still get 404 error message, and I truly have no idea what to do.. I was trying to fix it during the 2 days, and still hopeless:
When I click on the link on the index.jsp, insted of getting view.jsp page, I get:
 HTTP Status 404 - /WEB-INF/circle.jsp

**IDE: Intellij Idea 13**

**file structure:**
You can view my file structure here via this link:
http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/0007/2131/485459/150110/cc3837ee1a.jpg

**error img:**
You can vie my error img here via this link:
http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/0007/2131/485459/150110/0c70f50d3c.jpg

**MainController.java**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("rectanglePoint")
private Shape rectanglePoint;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("rectangle")
private Shape rectangle;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("circle")
private Shape circle;


public MainController(){

}
@RequestMapping(value = "/rectanglepoint", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView rectanglePoint(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("message", rectanglePoint.square());
    modelAndView.setViewName("view");
return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/rectangle", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView rectangle(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("message", rectangle.square());
    modelAndView.setViewName("view");
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/circle", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView circle(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("message", circle.square());
    modelAndView.setViewName("view");
    return modelAndView;
}
}
```

**springframeworkmvc-servlet.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3-1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="controllers"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="rectanglePoint" class="classes.RectanglePoint">
<constructor-arg index="0" ref="pointleft"/>
<constructor-arg index="1" ref="pointright"/>
</bean>
<bean id="circle" class="classes.Circle">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="5"/>
</bean>
<bean id="rectangle" class="classes.Rectangle ">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="2"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="5"/>
</bean>

<bean id="pointleft" class="classes.Point">
    <constructor-arg name="x" value="1"/>
    <constructor-arg name="y" value="2"/>
</bean>
<bean id="pointright" class="classes.Point">
   <property name="x" value="2"/>
    <property name="y" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
<display-name>springframework</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springframeworkmvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springframeworkmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springframeworkmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**view.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
${message}
</body>
</html>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="/circle.do">link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the image you posted I don't see any file with name circle.jsp

Comment: in your index.jsp page try changing /circle.do to /view.do, if this works let me know I will post an answer :D

Comment: Nope, it didnt help. Answering on your first question: As I understand, I dont need to directly create circle.jsp - It will be created automaticaly via Spring MVC( and exactly MainController.java in my case), am I right?

Comment: yes you are correct, I didn't see the last lines in your controller where you are setting the view name :) It will not be created by spring, spring will map the url and goto controller's appropriate method there you are setting view name("view"), then view resolver will resolve to appropriate view.

Comment: what is the exact url thats coming in browser when you try to navigate on circle.do?

Comment: The exact URL is:"http://localhost:8080/circle.do" but I get the    "HTTP Status 404 - /WEB-INF/circle.jsp"

Comment: I would suggest you to look at the view resolver, its url based view resolver, so I guess its looking for circle.jsp try changing the name of your jsp from view to circle.jsp

Comment: Thanks, I've just created circle.jsp in web-inf which should print out message , and the app finds it, although it doesnt work properly(I dont get message ). I will be working on it, thank you so much for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your support. I, by accedent, have found the misstake:

in MainController.java I've imported by IDEA suggest org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView; insted of import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView; Now it works fine. Thanks.